# Display 2 columns for each header

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table People (Id, Gender, Name).
Gender is either Male or Female. There can be many people with the same name.
I would like to write a query that displays for each gender the top 2 names
by count and their count, like this:

```
  Male        Female
Adam   23    Rose  34
Max    20    Jenny 15
```

I think that PIVOT might be used but all the examples I have seen display only one column for each header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on SQL Fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3477/1

This uses an couple of common table expressions to separate the genders.

```
create table People 
(
 Id int, 
 Gender varchar(50), 
 Name varchar(50)
)
;

insert into People values (1, 'Male', 'Bob');
insert into People values  (2, 'Male', 'Bob');
insert into People values  (3, 'Male', 'Bill');
insert into People values (4, 'Male', 'Chuck');

insert into People values (5, 'Female', 'Anne');
insert into People values (6, 'Female', 'Anne');
insert into People values (7, 'Female', 'Bobbi');
insert into People values (8, 'Female', 'Jane');

with cteMale as
(

    select Name as 'MaleName', Count(*) as Num, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by count(*) desc, Name) RowNum
    from People 
    where Gender = 'Male'
    group by Name

)
,
 cteFemale as
(
  select top 2 Name as 'FemaleName', Count(*) as Num, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by count(*) desc, Name) RowNum
  from People 
  where Gender = 'Female'
  group by Name

)

select a.MaleName, a.Num as MaleNum, b.femaleName, b.Num as FemaleNum
from cteMale a
  join cteFemale b on 
    a.RowNum = b.RowNum
where a.RowNum <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a windowing function.  Below is a complete solution using a temporary table #people.

-- use temp db
use tempdb;
go

-- drop test table
--drop table #people;
--go

-- create test table
create table #people (my_id int, my_gender char(1), my_name varchar(25));
go

-- clear test table
delete from #people;

-- three count
insert into #people values 
(23, 'M', 'Adam'),
(34, 'F', 'Rose');
go 3

-- two count
insert into #people values 
(20, 'M', 'Max'),
(15, 'F', 'Jenny');
go 2

-- one count
insert into #people values 
(20, 'M', 'John'),
(15, 'F', 'Julie');
go

-- grab top two by gender
;
with cte_Get_Top_Two as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY my_gender ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS my_window, 

my_gender, my_name, count(*) as total 
from #people
group by my_gender, my_name
)
select * from cte_Get_Top_Two where my_window in (1, 2)
go

Here is the output.

[image]

PS:  You can drop my_id from the table since it does not relate to your problem but does not change solution.

Comment: I wanted F and M to be headers, not rows. Charles answer works for me.

Comment: A database uses relational algebra.  IE - rows, If you want it pretty printed like about, use a reporting tool.